# changing s3 storages with django-storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I have a Django application where I use django-storages and amazon s3 to store images.
I need to move those images to a different account: different user different bucket.

I wanted to know how do I migrate those pictures?
my main concern is the links in my database to all those images, how do I update it?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is relative to the amazon storage address you provide in your settings. so you only need to move the images to a new bucket and update your settings.